# How to use javascript to trigger a modal one after another

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

I want to use the code below to accomplish the following flow:

1. validate user's input (form in a modal pop up)
2. if no error, trigger another modal to show something.  The content of the result modal comes from an ajax call.

The problem is the result modal never shows.

Edited: The problem seems in relation to e.preventDefault() as I tested with another version which makes the ajax call in $("#frmSchPkg").submit(function(e).
It works with preventDefefalut and doesn't work if preventDefault() is missing.

Perhaps the question is how to add preventDefault() to this posted javascript.

```js
$.validate({
  form: '#frmSchPkg',
  onSuccess: function($form) {
    var pkgnum12 = $("#pkgnum12").val();
    var dataString = 'pkgnum12=' + pkgnum12;
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "admin/sch_pkg_c.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data); // able to see data being expected. so the ajax call is successful
        $('#text-modal').modal('hide'); // tried to comment this out for testing, 1st modal vanishes anyway at this point
        $('#LookupResultModal').find('.ct_schpkgresult').html(data);
        $('#LookupResultModal').modal('show');
      },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="modal fade text-modal" id="text-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="smallModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm2">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-shop">
        <a class="close-modal" href="#" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span class="menu-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <h2 class=""><b>Search</b></h2>
      </div>
      <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="frmSchPkg">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <input class="form-control" name="pkgnum12" id="pkgnum12" type="text" placeholder="enter tracking number" data-validation="number length" data-validation-length="12-12" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="col-sm-6">

          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <button name="btnfind" id="btnfind" type="submit" class="clsfind btn btn-store btn-block">
              <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Search</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="LookupResultModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="LookupResultModal" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog ">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-shop">
        <a class="close-modal" href="#" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span class="menu-icon"></span>
        </a>
        <h2 class=""><b>Search Result</b></h2>
      </div>

      <div class="ct_schpkgresult"></div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you at least format your code properly? Its no fun having to scroll to read due to lazy question asking - meaning the HTML mainly!

Comment: You might want to use the library bootstrap-modal: http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/bs3.html It automatically handles multiple modals.

Comment: Thx Daniel.  I tried to follow to link's suggestion.  I added "data-toggle" and "href"  to the button.  The result modal shows up regardless input error occurred.  It seems data-toggle is causing the form validator not functioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution:

```js
$.validate({
  form: '#frmSchPkg',
  onSuccess: function(form) {
    return $.sendFormDataViaAJAX(form);
  }
});

$.sendFormDataViaAJAX = function(form) {
  var pkgnum12 = $("#pkgnum12").val();
  var dataString = 'pkgnum12=' + pkgnum12;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "admin/sch_pkg_c.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $('#text-modal').modal('hide');
      $('#LookupResultModal').find('.ct_schpkgresult').html(data);
      $('#LookupResultModal').modal('show');
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
  return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The JS script should be like

1. Ajax method should be inside validation `onSuccess: function($form) { }`
2. First modal `hide` and 2nd modal `show` should be in side Ajax method `success: function(data) { }`

   ```
   $.validate({
     form: '#frmSchPkg',
     onSuccess: function($form) {
       var pkgnum12 = $("#pkgnum12").val();
       var dataString = 'pkgnum12=' + pkgnum12;
       alert(dataString);
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "admin/sch_pkg_c.php",
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
           success: function(data) {
             console.log(data);
             $('#text-modal').modal('hide'); //If all good hide first modal
             $('#LookupResultModal').modal('show'); //show 2nd modal
             $('#LookupResultModal').find('.ct_schpkgresult').html(data); //show response in 2nd modal
           },
           error: function(err) {
             console.log(err);
           }
         });
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for reply.  Tried your code but can't even see the alert this time.

Comment: did you see anything in `console.log(data);`, this will not show any alert now `alert(dataString);` remove it or place it before the `$.ajax`

Comment: sorry,  can you guide me how to see console log?

Comment: press F12 from keyboard will open the browser console log window and look for console tab

Comment: I found developer tool from Chrome and there is a console tab.  I do see some errors but those do not seem related, like can't find some css file, can't find modernizr.js

Comment: I moved the alert to before ajax and the alert shown,  In my original I was able to see alert after success of ajax call.

Comment: great, if you see values in alert means data posting via ajax, but don't know what is inside the `sch_pkg_c.php` how you are handling the POST request

Comment: the sch_pck_c.php is to  pull data from database and formatted for modal body.  I added "async: false" for the ajax call and move the alert back to after success of ajax call.  I am able to the content of data (console.log). So it means the ajax call was done successfully. But somehow the result modal just not showing up.

Comment: a revision of Shehary's code. ajax call type changed to "GET" otherwise an error message will occur in the called php.  I revised my originally code with Shehary's concept.

Comment: Not really but seems getting closer.  Changing POST to GET makes the ajax call successful.  I further compare another old version on which form validation part wasn't working properly but was able to see the 2nd modal.  I found the preventDefault() makes a difference.